# After installing Windows Server 2008, what is the default password for the local Administrator account?

Tags: windows-server-2008, password, installation

The first time I installed Server 2008, I thought to myself, "I don't remember being asked to set the password." So I installed it a second time and am now certain that it must be asking for a default password.

Comment: Doh! The default password was blank... and I must have changed it weeks ago when I fist got this test system up and running.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default Administrator password is blank and you're required to change it on the first logon.

Answer (score 1):

I know this probably doesn't help too much but after you set a password here is some info on the password policies for 2008 server.

Like Evan said, the default password should be blank unless you accidentally put something in without realizing it.

[MS Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc264456.aspx)